# How to use (AS) TOTAL in where, on mssql?

Tags: sql-server, where-clause

How to use (AS) TOTALNAME in where

```
SELECT 
   *, CITY + ' / ' + NAME AS TOTALNAME
FROM 
   FARKETMEZ
WHERE
   TOTALNAME like '%TURKEY%'
```

Comment: you can not use column alias in where clause of same level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the `ALIAS` that was given on the same level as the `WHERE` clause.

You have two choices:

- by using the expression directly

query:

```
SELECT  *, CITY + ' / ' + NAME AS TOTALNAME
FROM  FARKETMEZ
WHERE TOTALNAME like '%TURKEY%'
```

- by wrapping in a subquery

query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(    SELECT  *, CITY + ' / ' + NAME AS TOTALNAME
    FROM  FARKETMEZ
) a
WHERE TOTALNAME like '%TURKEY%'
```

The SQL Order of Operation is as follows:

- FROM clause
- WHERE clause
- GROUP BY clause
- HAVING clause
- SELECT clause
- ORDER BY clause

The reason why can't use it directly is because the `WHERE` clause is executed first before the `SELECT` statement in which the `ALIAS` is being created.

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly, either use a derived table, or you can use a CTE (SQL Server 2005+):

Derived table:

```
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT 
           *, CITY + ' / ' + NAME AS TOTALNAME
        FROM 
           FARKETMEZ
      ) AS T
WHERE TOTALNAME like '%TURKEY%'
```

CTE:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
           *, CITY + ' / ' + NAME AS TOTALNAME
    FROM 
       FARKETMEZ
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE 
WHERE TOTALNAME like '%TURKEY%'
```